# How to mount a Synology Diskstation NAS

Tags: mount, fstab, nas, plex

I am a long time Windows person, with a little experience in Ubuntu. I am trying to set up Plex Media Server on a new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine. My video library is on a Synology Diskstation NAS named Sequoia2, and for the life of me (at least the past 3 hours of it) I have been unable to configure the Movies and TV library sections in Plex. These are located on the NAS (in Windows-speak) in \\Sequoia2\video\Movies and \\Sequoia2\video\TV.

Unfortunately, I am finding all sorts of posts with all sorts of ways of doing this, and I've tried several with no success. Surely there must be a well accepted, "right" way to go about this. I don't want Plex to lose these connections after a reboot, and from what I can tell, this will involve creating a mount in fstab. Could someone tell me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SMB setup guide:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

NFS setup guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Have you been trying the setup via SMB or NFS?
I would recommend the NFS connection in general for the persistent connections.

Comment: Thanks, before you answered, I was finally able to configure NFS with the help of this blog post: http://www.ryananddebi.com/2013/01/15/linuxmint-or-ubuntu-how-to-automount-synology-shares/